# How to add menu item in default system menu

Tags: android, menu

Can you please suggest to me how to add a menu item in the system menu? For example, I would like to add a shortcut to my application in the system contacts menu.

Comment: in 1 word you can not do this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate into contacts , try this :

http://www.mostlybaked.com/android-contacts-integration

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html